# Read XML Root Attribute Value in Classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic, root

I've the following XML

```
<response key="12345">
  <colours>
  <colour>Red</colour>
  <colour>Blue</colour>
  </colours>
</response>
```

In Classic ASP how do I access the value of key in the root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
dim xmlDoc : set xmlDoc = sever.createobject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
dim node : set node = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//response")
dim attrValue : attrValue = node.getAttribute("key")
```